# add a new field to existing module odoo 8

Tags: python, odoo

I want to add a new field in my opportunities view in sales module. I've created a new module .when I try to install,  it is showing following error (mentioned in snap) -

[image]

Below is  my form where I want to add the field.

[image]

Following is `.py` file :

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import datetime
import math
from datetime import date
from openerp.osv import osv, fields, orm

class crm_lead(osv.osv):
    _inherit = "crm.lead"
    _description="modification"
    _columns = {
        'quantite': fields.text('Quantité'),
    }
```

And this is `xml` file :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record id="crm_case_tree_view_oppor" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">crm.case.tree.view.oppor</field>
            <field name="model">crm.lead</field>
            <field name="view_type">tree</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="crm.crm_case_tree_view_oppor"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree>
                    <xpath expr="//field[@name='probability']" position="after">
                        <field name="quantite"/>
                    </xpath>
                </tree>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Comment: Have you removed your xml and checked if your py file has been initialised and the field has been added to the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed another view which inherits from the same tree view. Here is what they did. They did not use xpath, not sure why. I think I have before, however it is worth a try.

```
    <record id="view_crm_opportunity_geo_assign_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">crm.lead.geo_assign.tree.inherit</field>
        <field name="model">crm.lead</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="crm.crm_case_tree_view_oppor"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="partner_id" position="after">
                <field name="partner_assigned_id"/>
                <field name="date_assign" invisible="1"/>
             </field>
        </field>
    </record>
```

So I guess yours would look like this. You would have to change the name of the views to match your example but you probably get the idea.

```
    <record id="view_crm_opportunity_geo_assign_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">crm.lead.geo_assign.tree.inherit</field>
        <field name="model">crm.lead</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="crm.crm_case_tree_view_oppor"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="probability" position="after">
                <field name="quantite"/>
             </field>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Comment: I am really glad you are now moving forward!

Comment: i will do it with pleasure but how ?

Comment: I think if you are logged in and are looking at your own question there is a checkmark or some button that allows you to mark the answer as correct.

Comment: Thanks @ilham ! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Phillip Stack's answer is correct, but i want to mention two things here.

1. While using Odoo 8 please use the new API, because it's future-proof. The xml file wont change with it, so look for it in my point 2. The py module should look like:

```
from openerp import models, fields

class CrmLead(models.Model):
    _inherit = "crm.lead"
    _name = "crm.lead"  # optional

    quantite = fields.Text(string="Quantité")
```

2. You don't need to specify the view type when extending a view. Just define your extensions to the origin view. Your xml should look like in Phillip Stack's answer or for xpath like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record id="crm_case_tree_view_oppor" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">crm.case.tree.view.oppor</field>
            <field name="model">crm.lead</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="crm.crm_case_tree_view_oppor"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//field[@name='probability']" position="after">
                    <field name="quantite" />
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```